# Mongoose doesnt save multiline string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i try to put a multiline string into a mongoose database it doesnt want to work. It just saves one line of the string.

Logging content to console:

[image: Console output of string]

Website result:

[image]

EJS Code

```html
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
    <div class="card mb-2" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <% if(user.admin == true || user.id == post.authorid){ %>
            <form action="/deletepost/<%= post.id %>" method="post">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-block">Delete</button>
            </form>
            <br>
          <% } %>
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="http://mywebsite/profile/<%= post.authorid %>"><%= post.authorname %></a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><%= post.date %></h6>
          <hr>
          <p class="card-text"><%= post.content %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

Mongoose model:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String
  }
})
```

How i save to database:

```
var newPost = {content, authorid, authorname};
Post.create(newPost, function(err, newlyCreated){
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
 } else {
  res.redirect("/app")
 }
});
```

I use express & ejs if that matters.

Comment: Mongoose/Mongodb should keep the line breaks just as they exist in the string, can you show us the code for the ejs-template?

Comment: I have added the ejs code